# PyQt: Connecting a button in a dialog

Tags: python, button, pyqt, signals-slots

I'm writing my first PyQt program, but I have a problem with a pushbutton. I read some other Q&A's but I wasn't able to solve it.

Basically I have a main window with a menu bar. By clicking on the menu item "actionSelect", a new dialog called SelectFiles is opened. It contains a pushbutton called "ChooseDirButton" that should open the select directory widget and change the "ShowPath" linedit text with the selected directory.

My code looks like this:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
import sys

import TeraGui

class MainWindow(QMainWindow, TeraGui.Ui_MainWindow):
    path = ""

    def __init__(self, parent=None):       
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.actionSelect.triggered.connect(self.Select)

    def Select(self):
        dialog = QDialog()
        dialog.ui = TeraGui.Ui_SelectFiles()
        dialog.ui.setupUi(dialog)
        dialog.setAttribute(Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)
        dialog.exec_()

    def ChooseDirectory():
        global path
        path = str(QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self, "Select Directory"))
        self.ShowPath.setText(path)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
form = MainWindow()
form.show()
app.exec_()
```

I'm not able to let the ChooseDirectory method be executed when the pushbutton "ChooseDirButton" is clicked. I tried to connect them, but I do not understand the right syntax. Moreover there could be something wrong in the ChooseDirectory method also.
I created the GUI with Qt Designer and import it with the "import TeraGui" command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to create a subclass for your dialog, just as you did for the main window.

I can't actually test it without your ui modules, but something like this should work:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
import sys

import TeraGui

class MainWindow(QMainWindow, TeraGui.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.actionSelect.triggered.connect(self.Select)

    def Select(self):
        dialog = Dialog(self)
        dialog.exec_()
        self.ShowPath.setText(dialog.path)

class Dialog(QDialog, TeraGui.Ui_SelectFiles):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Dialog, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.ChooseDirButton.clicked.connect(self.ChooseDirectory)
        self.path = ''

    def ChooseDirectory(self):
        self.path = str(QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(
            self, "Select Directory"))

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
form = MainWindow()
form.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: It works! But I had to move the "self.ShowPath.setText(dialog.path)" command into the ChooseDirectory method and change it to "self.ShowPath.setText(self.path)".